# $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let me be honest, when some teacher ask me to calculate such limit, I always try to found two paths with different results to show that such limit don't exist.

But, I try four paths all fall at zero... and wolframalpha (internet boss (after math.stackexchange.com)) tells me this limit don't exit. Stewart's (book boss) calculus book tells me this limit is zero. But I don't know how to show this...

I hate limit calculus, because it's full of tricks... if you're not aware enough the day of your exam, you lost quickly some points...

Could you light my path?

thx to everybody!

Comment: Use polar coordinates :)

Comment: A general useful inequality is $|x|,|y|\leqslant \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, i.e. $|x|,|y|\leqslant \lVert (x,y)\rVert$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Convert into polar coordinates: so $x=r\cos\theta\space$ and $y=r\sin\theta.$

$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\=\displaystyle\lim_{r\to 0}\dfrac{r\cos\theta\cdot r\sin\theta}{\sqrt{r^2\cos\theta+r^2\sin\theta}}\\=\displaystyle\lim_{r\to 0}\dfrac{r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\sqrt{r^2(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)}} \text{Recall the Pythagorean Identity,}\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1.\\=\displaystyle\lim_{r\to 0}\dfrac{r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\sqrt{r^2}}\\=\displaystyle\lim_{r\to 0}\space r\sin\theta\cos\theta\\=0$

Comment: thx, I didn't expected the full answer. But thank you for your "latex" effort

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: double thx, because that limit was in my exam this morning

Comment: This doesn't show that the function is continuous at (0, 0).  There is always a possibility that the limit as (x,y) goes to (0, 0) along a curve (a path that is not a straight line) is not 0.  So this is not a complete proof.

Comment: @Nick How would you fix the proof? It looks like they fixed $\theta $ and let $r$ goes to zero.

Answer (score 11):

**Related problems:** [I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339400/find-the-limit-if-it-happens-to-exist-or-prove-it-doesnt-exist/339675#339675), [II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262874/show-that-g-is-continuous-at-0-0). Here is how you advance

$$ \Bigg| \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0  \Bigg |\leq   \frac{|x||y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \leq \frac{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}  }{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}< \epsilon =\delta .$$

**Note:**

> $$ |x| \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2},\quad |y| \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}. $$

Answer (score 5):

You could do the following: $x^2+y^2\geq 2|xy|$, so $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\geq \sqrt{2|xy|}$, therefore $$\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\leq\frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{2|xy|}}=\frac{\sqrt{|xy|}}{\sqrt{2}},$$ which converges to $0$ as $x,y\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The hint is to use the standard trick of the polar coordinates thing:

Put $x = r \cos \theta $, $y = r \sin \theta $.

Alternatively, you can see what happens if you approach the limit through the the line $y = x $.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't any "trick" here; just applying standard absolute value estimates and polar coordinates. As @Citizen mentioned, polar coordinates turns the inside of your limit to

$$\dfrac{r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}{r}.$$

Try it from there...