# Is this a correct proof for $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

**Proof:** Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. 
For our proof we need to find $\delta>0$ such that $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta\to|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0|\lt\varepsilon$

$x\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\,\,\,\,\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}\to\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le1,$
which implies$\frac{x|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le|y|\le\sqrt{y^2}\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, which is our condition for $\delta$.
So if we let $\varepsilon=\delta$ and $0\lt\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\lt\delta$, we have that:

$|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0|\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\lt\delta=\varepsilon.$
So by definition of the limit, $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0.$

Comment: Yes, only replace $x$ by $|x|$ in the 3rd and 4th lines.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709023/show-lim-limits-x-y-to0-0-fracxy-sqrtx2y2-0-using-delta-epsil?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps slightly simpler: $\;\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\;$ , and then

$$0\le\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\le\frac{|x||y|}{|x|}=|y|\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to(0,0)]{}0$$

Or with polar coordinates: $\;x=r\cos \theta\;,\;\;y=r\sin\theta\implies$

$$\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=r\cos\theta\sin\theta\xrightarrow[r\to0]{}0$$

Comment: I believe you mean $y = r \sin \theta$

Comment: @Jonas ZOf course, thank you very much. Edited

Comment: In the first paragraph you want to treat $x\ne0, x = 0$ separately.

Comment: @zhw. Thank you. I think you're right, yet by the complete symmetry of the expression and since we can (and must) assume that while $\;(x,y)\to (0,0)\;$ it is also true that $\;(x,y)\neq (0,0)\iff x\neq 0\;or\;y\neq0\;$ , so at least one of the coordinates isn't zero at any given point and thus we choose that one.